# Flash Cross-Domain Proof of Concept

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml

In the past, I have been able to successfully test insecure [Flash cross-domain policies](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Test_RIA_cross_domain_policy_(OTG-CONFIG-008)) by using tools such as the followings:

- https://thehackerblog.com/crossdomain/
- https://github.com/nccgroup/CrossSiteContentHijacking

The policy is a normal "wildcard" one and looks like this:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

However, in a current case I cannot make the usual proof of concept. Using the previous tools I get errors such as the followings:

```
ioErrorHandler: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]

openHandler: [Event type="open" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
```

I tried looking around on the Internet to pinpoint the issue, but got nowhere. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like someone also had this problem. You might want to take a look at this post on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800312/error-2032-stream-error-when-loading-a-remote-content